# ChartObject.Deactivate doesnt work?

Tags: excel, plot, charts, focus, vba

I can activate a chart very easily:

```
Sheet10.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
```

Now when I try to deactivate:

```
Sheet10.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Deactivate
```

I get an error:

> `"object doesn't support property or method"`

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Chart does not have method "deactivate". If you want to deactive a chart, just activate something else on the sheet (a cell for example).

Comment: Cheers RADO! But, conceptually do we not find that strange? If you can activate something, why cant you deactivate it?

Comment: Because you can't just "deactivate" to nothing. Something must be activated instead (to have focus).

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks, you have to make your own "NULL", cheers

Comment: You should avoid "activate" method. It's usually a source of pain, and in 99.99% situations it's not necessary.

Comment: The real question is why the heck did you need to activate it in the first place. What you did wrong is type random characters without bothering to verify what object type you're working with, and what members that type exposes.

Comment: seemingly I annoyed you. sorry. I am reatively new to programming, and VBA. I thought the question was reasonable? Why not? So I can avoid asking such question in the future

Comment: Do not ask questions like *WHY???*. Keep the content clean and professional.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, there is no such method as `Deactivate`.

So a solution for `Chart 2` to be not in the `Activate` state is to create another object, possibly hidden, let's say in Sheet99:

```
Sheet99.ChartObjects("hiddenChart").Activate
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot J. Chomel

Answer (score 0):

To deactivate a chartobject, I found this to work:

```
Windows(ActiveWorkbook.Name).Activate
```